# Woocommerce registration form validation not working

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation, woocommerce

I have added some new fields to my woocommerce registration form, but i can't validate these new fields.

There's my new fields

```
add_action('register_form','myplugin_register_form');
function myplugin_register_form (){
    $first_name = ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? $_POST['first_name']: '';
    $last_name = ( isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) ? $_POST['last_name']: '';
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="first_name">Prénom <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['first_name'] ); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="last_name">Nom <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['last_name'] ); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

And this is my filter for the validation according to the wordpress codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

```
function myplugin_registration_errors ($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.','mydomain') );

    return $errors;
}
```

When i submit my form, without the field $_POST['first_name'] it passe without errors.

What's the best way to do it?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

Please write this code in theme's/child theme's functions.php

```
/**
 * Validate the extra register fields.
 *
 * @param  string $username          Current username.
 * @param  string $email             Current email.
 * @param  object $validation_errors WP_Error object.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First Name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['last_name'] )  ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last Name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. In future it is usually more helpful to the OP if you can add further instructions on how to implement your solution as they may be beginner programmers. It also helps future readers of the post

Answer (score 2):

If you look in `woocommerce-fundtions.php` it check for `$woocommerce->error
-count() == 0` and then proceed. So, instead adding errors to wordpress `$errors` I would add errors to Woocommerce like `$woocommerce->add_error( $reg_errors->get_error_message() )`

So the code would be

```
add_filter('registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors' ), 10, 3);

function myplugin_registration_errors($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
        $woocommerce->add_error( 'first_name_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.','mydomain') );

    return $errors;
}
```